# Synonym split request - coincident

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently the tag [coincident](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coincident) is a synonym of [overlapping-features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overlapping-features). Should this relationship be dissolved?

Answer (score 3):

This synonym relationship should be removed, because they are not the same thing. Features can overlap without being coincident, and they can be coincident without overlapping. In GIS, while coincident *can* mean 'occurs at the same place' it is more commonly referred to in the context of a topology and means that the edges of two features share *all* common vertices where they are adjoining.

Comment: I think you are probably right so I have removed the synonymy to try and take a look at the four questions tagged [tag:coincident].  I'll just have to wait about for some background process to recognize that they are no longer synonyms.  After that we may need to review/retag [these questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=coincident+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks. Tried to apply it this afternoon and didn't realize it was a synonym until after I'd saved the edit and saw the other tag appear. I was like, I didn't type that! :) I see it no longer sees them as synonym, but it's still showing the other tag's questions at the moment. I seem to recall there were four with the actual coincident tag, but your search to review wouldn't be a bad idea.